# Symfony : Get key value from object doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have this array of objects with doctrine,
how do i scope out one of the values?

This doesnt seem to work for me : todolist[0]->todo_body

```
todolist
(
    [0] => AppBundle\Entity\Todo Object
    (
        [todo_id:AppBundle\Entity\Todo:private] => 1
        [todo_body:AppBundle\Entity\Todo:private] => Install Symfony
    )

    [1] => AppBundle\Entity\Todo Object
    (
        [todo_id:AppBundle\Entity\Todo:private] => 2
        [todo_body:AppBundle\Entity\Todo:private] => Learn Symfony
    )

    [2] => AppBundle\Entity\Todo Object
    (
        [todo_id:AppBundle\Entity\Todo:private] => 3
        [todo_body:AppBundle\Entity\Todo:private] => Create Controller
    )

    [3] => AppBundle\Entity\Todo Object
    (
        [todo_id:AppBundle\Entity\Todo:private] => 4
        [todo_body:AppBundle\Entity\Todo:private] => Create first page
    )

)
```

Comment: `todolist[0]->getTodoBody` you need to use getters from your entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, but first be sure to have in your entity the getter `getTodoBody`:

```
todolist[0]->getTodoBody()
```

If you don't have the getter inside TodoEntity add this:

```
public function getTodoBody() {
    return $this->todo_body;
}
```

If you need todo_body inside your html template try this:

```
{{ todo.TodoId }}
```

or

```
{{ todolist[0].todo_body }}
```

Comment: This works in the controller,
but i need to get these values in my twig template to show a list of the values. This won't work in the template

Comment: I found it {{ todo.TodoId }}

Comment: Update answer with todolist[0].todo_body

Comment: ok so glad to help you! Accept the answer to help oher guys with your same problem!
@Keutelvocht

Answer (score 1):

`AppBundle\Entity\Todo` properties like 'todo_body' are clearly private (as stated in dump that you've provided) and therefore you cannot access them directly from outside with `$todo->todo_body`.

You need a getter method to access such properties.

You can try with something like `$todolist[0]->getTodoBody()` if you already have a getter in your `AppBundle\Entity\Todo` class.

If not, you will need to create it in first place. It would look something like:

```
public function getTodoBody() {
    return $this->todo_body;
}
```

And similar for `todo_id`